# Weka in Matlab: why it works using wrong attributes?

Tags: matlab, weka

I'm trying to import some tests from Weka to Matlab. I've already created a model with Weka 3.7 and now I want to reproduce the results in Matlab. 
First, I've created the sets traindata and testdata, for example I have:

```
> ...
> @attribute Tmp numeric
> @attribute Hum numeric
> @attribute Wsp numeric
> @attribute Wnd numeric
> @attribute class {IN,no}
> @data ...
```

and then, I load the model and I obtain the predictions with:

```
classifier = weka.core.SerializationHelper.read('myMIX750.model');
numInst = testdata.numInstances();
pred = zeros(numInst,1);
predProbs = zeros(numInst, traindata.numClasses());
for i=1:numInst
     pred(i) = classifier.classifyInstance( testdata.instance(i-1) );
     predProbs(i,:) = classifier.distributionForInstance( testdata.instance(i-1) );
end
```

...and it works! But, by mistake I introduced an erroneus input file, my model is this:

```
disp( char(classifier.toString()) )

J48 pruned tree
------------------
WxCat = 0: 0 (14003.0)
WxCat = 1
|   WndVar <= 0
|   |   PcpCatVar <= 1.00015: 0 (4436.0/389.0)
|   |   PcpCatVar > 1.00015: 1 (2499.0/143.0)
|   WndVar > 0: 1 (18636.0/1592.0)
```

Note as the attributes of the traindata/testdata are different from those in the model. However, the code it works and it returns a classification...

```
=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===
                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 1,000    1,000    0,500      1,000    0,667      0,000    0,500     0,500     IN
                 0,000    0,000    0,000      0,000    0,000      0,000    0,500     0,500     no
Weighted Avg.    0,500    0,500    0,250      0,500    0,333      0,000    0,500     0,500
```

Thus, how weka classify these instances containing different attributes to those used by the model?

This is the rest of the code I use:

```
eval = weka.classifiers.Evaluation(traindata);

eval.evaluateModel(classifier, testdata, javaArray('java.lang.Object',1));

fprintf('=== Run information ===\n\n')
fprintf('Scheme: %s %s\n', ...
    char(classifier.getClass().getName()), ...
    char(weka.core.Utils.joinOptions(classifier.getOptions())) )
fprintf('Relation: %s\n', char(traindata.relationName))
fprintf('Instances: %d\n', traindata.numInstances)
fprintf('Attributes: %d\n\n', traindata.numAttributes)

fprintf('=== Classifier model ===\n\n')
disp( char(classifier.toString()) )

fprintf('=== Summary ===\n')
disp( char(eval.toSummaryString()) )
disp( char(eval.toClassDetailsString()) ) %Detailed Accuracy By Class
disp( char(eval.toMatrixString()) )  %Confusion Matrix
```

Thanks in advance!

pgam

Comment: You need to be more specific and clear in your question